# How can i sign multiple files in one go using signtool?

Tags: signtool

I have a directory with dll's and .exe files. I want to sign them using the following command

```
 smctl sign --keypair-alias <keypair alias> --certificate <Path to code signing certificate> --input    "c:\testapp\test_a1.dll"
```

But there are a number of dll's i want to sign, they will all start with test_ though.

I have tried

```
  smctl sign --keypair-alias <keypair alias> --certificate <Path to code signing certificate> --input    "c:\testapp\test_*.dll"
```

but doesnt work , it says cant find file or path.
Any ideas on how i can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could execute it using PowerShell script and use PowerShell's Get-ChildItem cmdlet to get the list of dll files, and then use that list in a foreach loop where you can execute the command.

```
$folderPath = "c:\testapp"

# Get all DLL and EXE files and iterate through each file
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".dll" -or $_.Extension -eq ".exe" } | ForEach-Object {

    $filePath = $_.FullName

    # Execute your command with $filePath as a parameter
    smctl sign [other parameters] --input $filePath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The command line interface (CLI) you are using, [`smctl sign`](https://docs.digicert.com/pt/digicert-keylocker/tools/command-line-interface/smctl-command-manual/manage-signatures.html#-en--sign-488632), is provided by the [Singing Manager Controller (SMCTL)](https://docs.digicert.com/pt/digicert-keylocker/tools/signing-tools/smctl.html) from Digicert.  When configured to run on Windows, as hinted by your title, it is integrated with Microsoft's native [`signtool sign`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool#sign-command-options) command.   But the platform independent command line syntax of `smctl sign`, including how to specify files to be signed, remains different than that of `signtool sign`.

As you have shown, to sign a single file, you provide the file name as an argument of the "--input" option.   But to sign more than one file, you must instead specify the name of a folder containing all files you want to sign.   So if the folder "c:\testapp" contains only the DLLs you want to sign, pass that via the "--input" option as follows to fix your issue:

```
smctl sign --keypair-alias <keypair alias> --certificate <Path to code signing certificate> --input "c:\testapp"
```

If using the wildcard syntax is important, ask your administrator if the [Sign Authenticode files with SignTool on Windows](https://docs.digicert.com/pt/digicert-keylocker/signing-tools/sign-authenticode-files-with-signtool-on-windows.html) feature is available as an alternative.   If so, you could use `signtool sign` via the CMD processor, which would expand your wild card pattern.  But remember, as the name implies, this technique would not work for Linux or Mac operating systems.